# Write to proc in a kernel module which uses also a character device

Tags: c, linux, timer, linux-kernel

I have a kernel module which implements a timer and it works. At the same time I am able to create a new kernel module to write and read from proc. What I don't understand is how to combine the two operations in the same kernel module.

My application works in this way. A user program writes to the kernel module a number `n` which is used to create a timer that will expire in `n` milliseconds. To do so I implemented the `write` and `read` functions and I linked them to the `struct file_operations` which I use in the `init` function to register my character device (the timer).

Now for the `proc` file I need to declare a `write` and `read` function as well which should handle the requests from the user program. This is what confuses me, I cannot understand how to combine everything together.

Comment: Just define two **different** `struct file_operations` variables. Use one for character device, and another - for proc file. They are actually independent.

Comment: @Tsyvarev But I need to write the number `n` that user provides into proc, so in my module the timer and proc are not independent.

Comment: @David he meant the file operations are independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Tsyvarev mentioned use different file_operations

```
static struct proc_dir_entry *procfs;

static const struct file_operations proc_fops = {
 .owner = THIS_MODULE,
 .open  = open_proc_fn,
 .read  = read_proc_fn,
};

static const struct file_operations char_fops = {
 .owner = THIS_MODULE,
 .open  = open_char_fn,
 .read  = read_char_fn,
 .write = write_char_fn, 
};


int __init init_mod (void) {
   procfs = proc_create("filename", 0, NULL, &proc_fops);
   if(!proc)
       return -1;
   <Register char device with &char_fops >
   return 0;
}
```